# Client side throttling error while running skaffold dev

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, skaffold

[Link](https://github.com/oliviaflexx/quizlet-clone/tree/24b8d524ba428b8e33c7412d6b14926199fdb0e7) to the github

I'm trying to build a microservices application and when I ran Skaffold dev yesterday it worked fine but today when I run it I get this error:

```
I1106 19:00:53.703569    7794 request.go:668] Waited for 1.558340853s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: 
GET:https://34.72.125.232/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/replicasets?labelSelector=app%!D(MISSING)auth-mongo
 - deployment/classes-mongo-depl is ready. [10/14 deployment(s) still pending]

I1106 19:01:10.207249    7794 request.go:668] Waited for 1.067757889s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: 
GET:https://34.72.125.232/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=app%!D(MISSING)suggestions-mongo%!C(MISSING)skaffold.dev%!F(MISSING)run-id%!D(MISSING)7345a149-46a4-414f-85f9-a1b18a9a47e3
```

Comment: Could you please open an issue against the Skaffold repository with logs from running `skaffold dev -vdebug` (suitably redacted)?  I suspect our status-checking support, which issues `kubectl rollout status`, is hammering your server too much. https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/new

Comment: "client-side throttling, not priority and fairness" could happen if using an old kubectl version. I had similar error with `oc` (OpenShift client), and it was resolved using the [latest oc version](https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v4/clients/ocp/latest/openshift-client-linux.tar.gz)

Comment: I've opened an issue at https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/7012

Comment: @BriandeAlwis the error stopped when I allocated more nodes to my cluster. I think the issue was I had too many services and not enough nodes to handle them